# How to move placeholder up while typing in the textfield? is it possible just from storyboard? or code in IOS Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield, objective-c-blocks

I have set the values of placeholder

```
self.baseURLTextField.placeholder = ServiceUrl_English;
self.paymentBaseURLTextField.placeholder = PAYMENTSERVICEURL_ENGLISH;
```

I just want to move the placeholder up while editing or typing in textfield. is it possible through just only storyboard? or code in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the way you intended it. Placeholder is just a hint of what should be typed in the textField and it's supposed to be removed once text entry starts.

If you want the placeholder to "move up" I suggest you either prefill the textField with the text you want to preserve, or simply add the text at the point user starts typing in, and move the cursor to where you want the user text to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by putting a `UILabel` at the top of the text view then show/hide it whenever the user starts typing.

Or you can use a pod like [JVFloatLabeledTextField](https://github.com/jverdi/JVFloatLabeledTextField)